# Regex to match groups by digit

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
digits = '122223444'
```

expected:

```
['1', '2222', '3','444']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture group and back reference

```
(\d)\1*
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/fyCfFr/2/)  | [`Python demo`](https://onlinegdb.com/SJetPiHwr)

---

```
import re
regex = r"(\d)\1*"  
test_str = "122223444"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match at least one of each digit separately, for example with the `0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+` regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(\w)\1*", digits)]
```

**Example**:

```
import re

digits = '122223444'
print([m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(\w)\1*", digits)])
# ['1', '2222', '3', '444']
```

---

You can also do a `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

digits = '122223444'   
print([''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(digits)])
# ['1', '2222', '3', '444']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
match = re.match(r"(0+)(1+)(2+)(3+)(4+)(5+)(6+)(7+)(8+)(9+)", '122223444', re.I)
if match:
    items = match.groups()
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 1):

This expression,

```
((.)\2*)
```

or for digits only,

```
(([0-9])\2*)
```

in full match might be desired.

#### Test

```
import re


regex = r"((.)\2*)"
string = """
122223444
aaabbbbcddee
"""

l = []
for group in re.findall(regex, string):
    l.append(group[0])

print(l)
```

#### Output

```
['1', '2222', '3', '444', 'aaa', 'bbbb', 'c', 'dd', 'ee']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5t16PJ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/5t16PJ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---